# Unit testing DoFn with ProcessContext in argument list

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, data-processing

I trying to test the following ParDo handler:

```
public class DoFnHandlerFn extends DoFn<KV<Row, Row>, Row> {

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(@NotNull ProcessContext ctx, @SideInput("si_1") Map<Row, Iterable<Row>> si_1, @SideInput("si_2") List<Row> si_2) {
        var el = ctx.element();
        
    }
}
```

But I have difficulty creating ProcessContext instance!
I tried

```
var el = new DoFn.ProcessContext();
```

But I don't allowed to do it with error message: `'org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn' is not an enclosing class`

How can I instantiate  ProcessContext object in order to test it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a TestPipeline? I don't think you need to create a ProcessContext.

I think this document might be helpful to clarify some of the concepts: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/test-your-pipeline/